# writing xpath locator for a link element using xpath axes

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to learn Selenium and am trying to write the xpath locator for the "About Us" link on the web page - www.hdfc.com

I can do it with link as:

link=About Us

I have tried the following and it works fine:

xpath=//a[text()='About Us']

but I wanted to write the locator using xpath axes so that its flexible enough. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Did you get needed element successfully or you need child/parent of that element? At least take a look at the http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp

Comment: Why do you need to use XPath? Why does the link text locator not work?

Comment: The link locator worked for me but I am trying to understand the xpath axes method for traversing the Dom. So just wanted to figure out the xoath axes locator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case you have put forward the best selector you could use is ID, this is because IDs (much like classnames etc) are not dependent on the structure of the document at all but more about the content or purpose of the element. in this case you would want something like:

```
driver.findElements(By.Id("ic-aboutUs");
```

Another thing you should be aware of in general is that xpath expressions are considered a worse way to identify your elements than the use of CSS selectors, especially if you are testing in IE as the xpath implementation there is not native and is very slow. I suggest reading over http://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors for a brief look at some examples and also maybe have aread of http://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/selenium-xpath-marks-the-spot in order to see some of the negatives of using xpath.

Comment: Thing is, if you fancy a nice walk through the DOM (either up *or* down it), then you will be *bound* to XPath. CSS selectors won't help you here.

Comment: True enough, but times to use xpath are exceptions and not the rule and if someone is setting out to learn a set of selectors I would vote CSS first every time.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I just wanted to inderstand, how I could create an xpath query using ancestor / descendent functions. I have read the w3 wiki on xpath axes but that left me a bit in the haze.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below xpaths to detect 'About Us'link in your web page

1. Below xpath was written by refering the immediate parent node
   //li[@class='expanded']/child::span[text()='About Us']
2. This xpath was written by using the parent node of Menu bar(parent of whole menu items)
   //ul[@class='menu hdfc-investor']/child::li[contains(.,'About Us')]